# Has Anyone Customized StyleCop rules based on the IDesign Coding Standard?

Tags: stylecop

Has Anyone Customized StyleCop rules based on the IDesign Coding Standard?

Comment: I hadn't heard of this until now; thanks!  Interestingly though, it seems these IDesign guidelines conflict with a number of default FxCop and StyleCop rules.  How does one reconcile the various recommendations coming from MS?

Comment: Have you found a ruleset for the IDesign coding standard?

Answer (score 1):

you might want to try [Code Style Enforcer](http://codestyleenforcer.com/).  It manages rules based off the iDesign standard.

I think you can set a check in policy for any code analysis that's done at dev time.  If you go to Team Explorer -> Project name -> Right click on Settings -> Source Control you’ll see a Check-in Policy tab where you can add a Code Analysis policy.  There you can add a rule set that has been checked into TFS.  I think you should be able to access the Code Style Enforcer rules if you've installed them per the instructions on the page:

**Global Configurator**

1. In the start menu, select "Code Style Enforcer" and "Configurator".
2. Select where the global rules are to be located, e.g. a shared folder under source control, since the rules will be linked to a solution from here when selecting "Use Global Rules" in Visual Studio.
3. Configure the global rules that are most common for your solutions

Comment: I am looking for a rule set that can be used in TFS check in polices, not highlight during development.

Comment: Added more to response, hope that helps.